# Generating logic bricks with python in state 2

Tags: python, add-on, game-engine

I'm unable to create any logic bricks in state 2 or any other state except the main one.
How can I create a brick that will appear only in state 2?

Answer (score 1):

1. you have to click on that little arrow here:

[image]

2. then it will look like this:
   [image]

3. if you then click on another visible block there, you will see only the bricks for that state. And if you add controllers or whatever there, they will only be visible in that state.